# how to assign variable to module name in python function

Tags: python, module

I have a set of modules, and I want to be able to call one of them within a function based on an argument given to that function. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
from my.set import modules

def get_modules(sub_mod):
    variable = sub_mod
    mod_object = modules.variable
    function(mod_object)
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'variable'
```

It's not taking the argument I give it, which would be the name of a module that exists under my.set.modules. so if I called the function get_modules(name_of_mod_under_modules), I would like the line modules.variable to be "modules.name_of_mod_under_modules" which I could then have as an object passed to mod_object.

Comment: What do you expect `sub_mod` to be?

Comment: I would like for it to be a sub module within my.set.modules

Comment: Posted my answer, please see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code, you're looking for `modules.variable` which doesn't exist, hence the error! That's not how you get an attribute of an object.

To achieve what you wanted, use the `getattr` function.

```
mod_object = getattr(modules, variable)
```